# How to store MKPlacemark to Realm in ios (Swift 3)?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to stone a MKPlacemark instance to Realm. I think the way to stone Mkplacemark to CoreData is just to set the data type to transformable. But Realm only gets NSData. How can I convert a custom instance to NSData?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't directly store custom classes in Realm and there's no built in way to convert MKPlacemark into NSData, you should create your own Realm model, which has all properties of MKPlacemark that you need.
For example if you only need a name and a location, you could create this model:

```
class Placemark: Object {
    dynamic var longitude: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var latitude: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var name:String? = nil
}
```

And then you could create your own function that converts an instance of your Placemark class into an MKPlacemark object.

```
func getMKPlacemark(placemark: Placemark)->MKPlacemark{
    return MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: placemark.latitude,longitude: placemark.longitude))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this is the method that Realm team suggests to stone custom class and ios system's class. It's just a little inconvenient